# How do I implement a menu using jQuery and jQuery UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, menu, jquery-ui-menu

I am using jQuery v1.6.1 and jQuery UI 1.8.12 and, using those JavaScript libraries, I would like to implement a "simple" menu, similar to the one present in the StackOverflow website when hovering over the nickname.

Where I can find some useful tutorial or information about jQuery menus? What do you advise?

Comment: actually you do most of the things in css and html, jquery only provides you the visual effect

Answer (score 2):

Since you are already using jQuery UI have you looked at the Tabs widget?

http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

Comment: I have looked to that. How should I implement a menu using that?

Answer (score 0):

How about updating to JQuery UI 1.9 and then be using the [JQuery UI menu](http://blog.jqueryui.com/2010/06/jquery-ui-19m2-menu/)?

Comment: Is jQuery v1.9 a stable version? Can I use that in production mode?